# Adding data to datagridview using thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I am developing reporting application in c# and sql server. I am using threading to add data to `datagridview`. But still my UI freezes. I am new to multthreading and never used it before.

If any other technique is best suited for this please let me know. My main requrement is to add data to datagridview without freezing UI.

```
AggregateFunction fun=(AggregateFunction)Enum.Parse(typeof(AggregateFunction), cmbAggregateFunc.Text);
Thread thread = new Thread(() => prepareGrid(RowField, DataField, fun, ColumnFields));
thread.Start();

private void prepareGrid(string RowField, string DataField,AggregateFunction aggregateFun, List<string> ColumnFields)
{
    Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
    {
        (this.MdiParent as frmMain).progressBarTop.Style = ProgressBarStyle.Blocks;
        (this.MdiParent as frmMain).progressBarTop.Maximum = 100;
        (this.MdiParent as frmMain).progressBarTop.Value = 20;
        (this.MdiParent as frmMain).progressBarTop.Visible = true;
        (this.MdiParent as frmMain).toolStripLabelTop.Text = "Getting Data......";
    }));

    if (dgvGrid.InvokeRequired)
    {
        Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
        { dgvGrid.Visible = false; }));
    }
    
    Pivot pvt = new Pivot(dataTable);
    dtPivot = pvt.PivotData(
        RowField,
        DataField,
        aggregateFun,
        ColumnFields.ToArray<string>());

    
    Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
    {
        (this.MdiParent as frmMain).progressBarTop.Value = 80;
        (this.MdiParent as frmMain).toolStripLabelTop.Text = "Data Pivoted......";
    }));
    if (dtPivot == null)
    {
        Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
        {
            (this.MdiParent as frmMain).btn_Close.Enabled = true;
            (this.MdiParent as frmMain).progressBarTop.Visible = false;
            (this.MdiParent as frmMain).toolStripLabelTop.Text = "";                   
            (this.MdiParent as frmMain).btn_showReport.Enabled = true;
            MessageBox.Show("Sorry! Data Not Found.", Util.ApplicationName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);

            this.Close();
        }));
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
        {
            (this.MdiParent as frmMain).btn_Export.Enabled = true;
            (this.MdiParent as frmMain).btn_Close.Enabled = false;
        }));
    }

    bool isThreadedCall = (dgvGrid.InvokeRequired);
    string[] cols= (from dc in dtPivot.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>() select dc.ColumnName).ToArray();
    int totCols = cols.Count();
    Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
    {
        (this.MdiParent as frmMain).toolStripLabelTop.Text = "Generating Columns ";
        (this.MdiParent as frmMain).progressBarTop.Value = 0;
        (this.MdiParent as frmMain).progressBarTop.Maximum = totCols;
    }));
    for (int i = 0; i < totCols; i++)
    {
        if (isThreadedCall)
        {
            
            Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
                {
                    (this.MdiParent as frmMain).toolStripLabelTop.Text = "Generating Column " + i.ToString() + " of " + totCols.ToString();
                    (this.MdiParent as frmMain).progressBarTop.Value = i;
                    dgvGrid.Columns.Add(new DataGridViewColumn { Name = cols[i], HeaderText =cols[i], CellTemplate = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell(), ReadOnly = true, Visible = true });
                }));
        }
    }
    
    int totRows = dtPivot.Rows.Count;
    Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
    {
        (this.MdiParent as frmMain).progressBarTop.Value = 0;
        (this.MdiParent as frmMain).progressBarTop.Maximum = totRows;
    }));
    int iRow = 0;
    foreach (DataRow dr in dtPivot.Rows) 
    {
        if (isThreadedCall)
        {
            Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
                {
                    (this.MdiParent as frmMain).progressBarTop.Value = iRow;
                    (this.MdiParent as frmMain).toolStripLabelTop.Text = "Adding Row  " + iRow.ToString() + " of " + totRows.ToString();

                    dgvGrid.Rows.Add(dr.ItemArray);
                }));
        }
        iRow++;
    }           

    if (dgvGrid.InvokeRequired)
    {
        Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
        { dgvGrid.Visible = true; }));
    }
    Invoke(new MethodInvoker(delegate
    {
        (this.MdiParent as frmMain).btn_Close.Enabled = true;
        (this.MdiParent as frmMain).progressBarTop.Visible = false;
        (this.MdiParent as frmMain).toolStripLabelTop.Text = "";
    }));            
}
```

Comment: I usually use a BackGroundWorker instead of a thread to solve the lockup issue.

Comment: can you help me to achieve this in thready way.

Comment: I've never tried with thread.  I know BackgroundWorker does work.

Comment: There's no point in creating a new thread when the entirety of what you're having it do is just marshaling right back to the UI thread.  This is no different than just not making another thread, except with a lot more typing.

Comment: I don't see anything that's requiring a thread.  What's the long running operation?

Comment: some times the pivoted data has a long column list and adding it to the datagridview becomes long-running process I just want to keep the user informed and allow him to do other work till the datagridview  becomes ready with the data.